# Sorting Pandas Categorical labels after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I'm using `pd.cut` to discretize a dataset. Everything is working great. The question I have, however, is with the `Categorical` object type, which is the datatype returned by `pd.cut`. The docs say that the `Categorical` object is treated like an array of strings, so I'm not surprised to see that labels are lexically sorted when grouped.

For example, the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.randint(0, 10000, 100)})

labels = []
for i in range(0, 10000, 500):
    labels.append("{0} - {1}".format(i, i + 499))

df.sort(columns=['value'], inplace=True, ascending=True)
df['value_group'] = pd.cut(df.value, range(0, 10500, 500), right=False, labels=labels)

df.groupby(['value_group'])['value_group'].count().plot(kind='bar')
```

Produces the following chart:

[image]

(notice 500-599 in the middle)

Prior to grouping, the structure is in the order I expect:

```
In [94]: df['value_group']
Out [94]: 
59        0 - 499
58        0 - 499
0       500 - 999
94      500 - 999
76      500 - 999
95     1000 - 1499
17     1000 - 1499
48     1000 - 1499
```

I've played around with this for some time and the only way that I've been able to avoid this is to precede the label with a leading alpha char, e.g. `['A) 0 - 499', 'B) 500-999', ... ]` which makes me cringe. Other things I looked into are providing a custom groupby implementation, which didn't seem possible (or like the right thing either). What am I missing?

Comment: Please have a look at the following PR in pandas: This is currently worked on in pandas: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7217. This kind of operation should work with that PR (and if not it's a bug...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has bitten me too.  Probably the right fix is to improve native support for Categorical objects, but in the meantime I get around this in practice by doing a final sorting pass:

```
In [104]: z = df.groupby('value_group').size()

In [105]: z[sorted(z.index, key=lambda x: float(x.split()[0]))]
Out[105]: 
0 - 499        5
500 - 999      6
1000 - 1499    4
1500 - 1999    6
2000 - 2499    4
2500 - 2999    6
3000 - 3499    3
3500 - 3999    3
4000 - 4499    2
4500 - 4999    6
5000 - 5499    6
5500 - 5999    5
6000 - 6499    6
6500 - 6999    2
7000 - 7499    9
7500 - 7999    3
8000 - 8499    7
8500 - 8999    6
9000 - 9499    5
9500 - 9999    6
dtype: int64

In [106]: z[sorted(z.index, key=lambda x: float(x.split()[0]))].plot(kind='bar')
Out[106]: <matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0xbe87d30>
```

[image: demo with better order]

Answer (score 2):

[image]You can do a custom sort of your data.
Let's say:

```
group = df.groupby(['value_group'])['value_group'].count()
sortd= group.reindex_axis(sorted(group.index, key=lambda x: int(x.split("-")[0])))
```

And then if you plot the sortd series it works.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who actually makes it down to this part of the answers, simply add the `sorted=False` parameter to retain original sorting:

```
df.groupby(['value_group'], sorted=False)['value_group'].count().plot(kind='bar')
```